# JavaScript Value Change CheckBox

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking to change a value of a string if a checkbox has been checked:

```
<input id="checkbox-2" class="checkbox-custom" name="checkbox-group" type="checkbox">
```

So far I have no JavaScript solution but I would like to change to both values shown below, when the checkbox is checked:

```
<h3><i class="fa fa-check"></i> <span class="the-amount"><?= $stringvalue ?></span></h3>
<h3><b>TOTAL:</b> <span>$<?= $cost ?></span></h3>
```

Comment: Cool. So could you edit your question to include what you've done so far to try and figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would suggest to use jQuery.

```js
$("#checkbox-2").change(function(){
 $(this).is(":checked") ? $("#text").html("checked") : $("#text").html("unchecked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="checkbox-2" class="checkbox-custom" name="checkbox-group" type="checkbox">
<div id="text">checkstatus</div>
```

Comment: OP is not using Jquery.